# map loop return problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with a map loop.
I want to make a map on the props that are received but because of the delay in getting the props in the parent component the initial props that arrive is an empty array and after a second the real information arrives.
The problem is that I can not get the component to display the correct information.

```
export default function FriendsCards(props) {
  const [userFriends, setUserFriends] = useState(props.friends)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(props.friends.length != 0){
      setUserFriends(props.friends)
    }
  })

  return (
    <div className='friendsCon'>
      {
        userFriends.map(friend => {
          if(friend.profile){
            return(
              <div className='card'>
                <h3 className='name'>{friend.name}</h3>
                <img className='img' src={friend.profile.picture.data.url}/>
                <h4 className='adress'>{friend.userAdress}</h4>
                <h4 className='phone'>{friend.phoneNumber}</h4>
              </div>
            )
          } else {
            return(
              <div className='card'>
                <h3 className='name'>{friend.name}</h3>
                <h4 className='adress'>{friend.userAdress}</h4>
                <h4 className='phone'>{friend.phoneNumber}</h4>
              </div>
            )
          }
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You should be able to do it without using `useState` at all -- just render `props.friends` directly.

Comment: not working.. the map loop not return jsx

Comment: really? you replaced `userFriends` with `props.friends` and it didn't work?

Comment: It does not work because at first the prop is an empty array. and the code runs once without useEffect so nothing happens

Comment: @snir.hak Have you even tried following TKoLs advice?

Comment: yse my friend still not working

Comment: If the only thing you're willing to contribute here is repeating the phrase *"still not working"*, people will leave your question behind. I'd suggest being a lot more communicative. For example by showing/explaining **how** you followed the advice given, or how **exactly** it is not working after you applied the changes.

Comment: I wrote in the comment above why it does not work the initial value is an empty array

Comment: Yes you wrote that, but it is completely irrelevant with regards to what TKoL suggested you to do. If you followed their advice you would see that neither `useState` nor `useEffect` is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
export default function FriendsCards(props) {
  const [userFriends, setUserFriends] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(props.friends.length != 0){
      setUserFriends(props.friends)
    }
  }, [props?.friends])

  return (
    <div className='friendsCon'>
      {
        userFriends.length && userFriends.map(friend => {
          if(friend.profile){
            return(
              <div className='card'>
                <h3 className='name'>{friend.name}</h3>
                <img className='img' src={friend.profile.picture.data.url}/>
                <h4 className='adress'>{friend.userAdress}</h4>
                <h4 className='phone'>{friend.phoneNumber}</h4>
              </div>
            )
          } else {
            return(
              <div className='card'>
                <h3 className='name'>{friend.name}</h3>
                <h4 className='adress'>{friend.userAdress}</h4>
                <h4 className='phone'>{friend.phoneNumber}</h4>
              </div>
            )
          }
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if(props.friends.length != 0){
    setUserFriends(props.friends)
  }
},props])
```

what will this do ??
Ans : now when props will change then it will call this use effect again and your setUserFriends will get latest data

Comment: You're missing a `[` around `[props]`

Comment: useEffect(() => {
  if(props.friends.length != 0){
    setUserFriends(props.friends)
  }
},[props])

Comment: try above one friend

Comment: share your updated code again with my change